# maximizing file size for wordpress theming locally

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it necessary to host wordpress site to maximize file size? Can we do it locally in wamp server? I have made changes in `php.ini` file and also saved it in wp-admin folder but it doesnt work.

I have tried the following code in `.htaccess` folder:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
php_value max_execution_time 500
php_value max_input_time 500
```

and maximize file size as

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

But locally it is not working.

Comment: If you make changes to the php.ini file you have to restart the server

Comment: What does your `phpinfo` says

Comment: Restarted the server.. Still not working :(